# connection to adb is down

Tags: android, eclipse, adb

This is the very common question everyone asked, but none of the solutions helped me.

When I run the application in eclipse, I am getting this error :

The connection to adb is down, and a severe error has occurred.
You must restart adb and Eclipse.
Please ensure that adb is correctly located at

`D:\f drive\Android from c\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe' and can be executed`

Tried restarting adb and eclipse, but nothing helped and i have set java_home, android_home paths.

When I try opening SDK Manager, I get the following error:

```
[2016-04-19 15:16:43 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] The system cannot find the path specified
```

Through window --> preferences --> android --> I have set the correct sdk location

Comment: just restart your pc :D

Comment: Even that is done,
no use @RashidCordero

Comment: Have you changed your sdk location previosuly,If yes please specfiy it properly in eclipse.

Comment: i have changed the sdk location through preferences and even replaced with the old one through the same path. It is taking all the API's properly @LipanGhosh

Comment: If nothing is working out after trying everything I would suggest you to use Android Studio and configure  your same sdk and import your project.Please let us know if you are still facing the same problem

Comment: Okay. I will download android studio. Do we need to set any path for android studio to run it? @LipanGhosh

Comment: No just download it.And then import the your project.@Mounika